# TL494 minimum operating voltage VCC

Tags: pwm, dc-dc-converter, simulation, resonant-converter, tl494

Has anyone operated TL494 on +5VDC practically as it works in simulation software ?

minimum operating voltage indicated in datasheet is +7VDC .

please confirm.

Comment: That chip is something like 35 or 40 years old. There are much better choices, particularly for low supply voltage. It's the LM741 of switching power supply chips.

Answer (score 1):

If the datasheet say so, stick with it.

One reason is it has on-chip 5V reference so it need some margin for the reference to work normally.

Answer (score 1):

Please confirm? Sure:

[image]

It is written right there int he *Recommended Operating Conditions* page. This means that you should stick to it. If you go too high or too low, it means the IC may not work as intended.

If a Datasheet specifies a min and max operating voltage/current/temperature etc then **do not exceed it**. Doing so means the manufacturer cannot guarantee that the device will work, and therefore you have an incredibly unreliable design.

The only mention of 5V in the datasheet is to do with the reference voltage:
[image]

How do you think the IC can produce a stable 5V reference with a 5V supply? it just won't work. What is this used for?

[image]

Turns out this is a useful addition to this IC.

So, to conclude, the answer is no. Do not use a 5V supply for this IC. Stick with a minimum of 7V.

Comment: I know its a late comment to your answer but Thank you MCG for detailed answer !

Comment: @AnilKG no problem. If the answer was useful and/or answered your question, you can 'upvote' it by pressing the 'Up' arrow by on the left hand side of the answer, and accept it as the correct answer by clicking the tick.